# How to pass parameter to groovy post build in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have the following Groovy Postbuild script in a jenkins job:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
    import java.io.InputStreamReader
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter
    import java.net.URL
    import java.net.URLConnection
    
    def sendPostRequest(urlString, paramString) {
        def url = new URL(urlString)
        def conn = url.openConnection()
        conn.setDoOutput(true)
        def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream())
    
        writer.write(paramString)
        writer.flush()
        String line
        def reader = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            println line
        }
        writer.close()
        reader.close()
    }
    
    def result =" Project: *Autotests* \n Version *manager.build.buildVariables.get("VERSION_CURR")* \n"
    
    sendPostRequest("https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage", "parse_mode=Markdown&chat_id={id_Chat}&reply_to_message_id=&text=${result}")
```

But I am getting an error: "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: VERSION_CURR for class: Script1"

However, I have a string parameter:

[image]

i also tried: `def result =' Project: *Autotests* \n Version *${VERSION_CURR}* \n'`

Comment: Is your pipeline a declarative pipeline? If so can you share the pipeline as well?

Comment: Have a look at the [parameters section](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) of the online Pipeline Syntax document.